# margin between HTML5 fields is inaccurate when using a class

Tags: html, css

In the following version of a simple form for ["Personal Details"](https://codepen.io/SSteven/pen/BeKLav), the margins between the fields are displayed as desired.

The form shows 3 rows of fields:

1. Row 1 contains the "First Name" field and label.
2. Row 2 contains the "Last Name" field and label.
3. Row 3 is the row of interest and contains 2 fields (City and ZIP) between which a gap is displayed correctly, as desired.

(I have displayed a green border for the labels and blue border for the fields, for debugging.)

The relevant CSS is:

```
#city {
  width: 58%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

#ZIP {
  width: 40%;
}
```

The percentages here are 58, 2 (for the right-margin of the city field and 40, which add up to 100%. Thus these 2 fields fit in the row. As stated, this works correctly, as desired.

However, in the [following version](https://codepen.io/SSteven/pen/arNmvJ) of the same form, instead of specifying the right-margin within the field's CSS itself, I have created a class. Immediately, the layout breaks. The 2 fields (city and ZIP) no longer fit in a row. The ZIP field is then accommodated in the next row. In order to ensure the 2 fields do fit in a row, I then have to adjust the percentages as shown here. But then, the right edge of the ZIP field doesn't align with the right edges of the last field in the other rows.

The relevant CSS is as follows:

```
.lastfld {
  margin-right: 0;
}

#city {
  width: 58%;
}

#ZIP {
  width: 38%;
}
```

Note that now the percentages (2, 58 and 38) add up only to **98%**, leaving a gap after the ZIP field.

The relevant markup is as follows:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lbl">
    <label>City / ZIP</label>
  </div>

  <div class="col-flds">
    <input type="text" 
           id="city" name="city" 
           placeholder="City">

    <input type="text" 
           class="lastfld" 
           id="ZIP" name="ZIP" 
           placeholder="ZIP">
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to ask:

1. Semantically, I have not made any change. The change is only in syntax. Earlier, I put the `margin-right` property directly within the field. It worked. Later I just added it within a class and applied the class to the field in the markup. Yet the row broke. Why does this happen?
2. How can I solve this problem?
3. Is there any other way (using only block/inline-block/float) to get the desired result? **Note that for this snippet, I am not using flex or grid layout**, since this snippet would be part of a progressively enhanced program.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: navy;
}

.frm {
  /* border: 1px solid green; */
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  background-color: #f2f2f2; /* light gray */
}

.row {
  /*border: 1px dashed red;*/
  width: 100%;
  margin: 18px 0;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row::after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}

.col-lbl {
  display: inline-block;
  /*float: left;*/

  border: 1px dotted green;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
}

.col-flds {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;

  border: 1px dotted blue;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type="text"],
select,
textarea {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;

  border: 1px solid #ccc; /* light grey */
  margin-right: 2%; /* default right margin */
  padding: 12px 20px;
}

textarea {
  height: 200px;
  resize: none;
}

.lastfld {
  margin-right: 0;
}

input[type="text"]:focus,
select:focus,
textarea:focus {
  border: 2px solid #555;
}

#fname,
#lname {
  width: 100%;
}

#city {
  width: 58%;
}

#ZIP {
  width: 38%;
}
```

```html
<code>Please watch in full page view</code><br>
<h1>PERSONAL DETAILS - 3</h1>

<div class="frm">
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lbl">
        <label for="fname">First Name</label>
      </div>

      <div class="col-flds">
        <input type="text" class="lastfld" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your first name">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lbl">
        <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
      </div>

      <div class="col-flds">
        <input type="text" class="lastfld" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lbl">
        <label>City / ZIP</label>
      </div>

      <div class="col-flds">
        <input type="text" id="city" name="city" placeholder="City">

        <input type="text" class="lastfld" id="ZIP" name="ZIP" placeholder="ZIP">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the selector `input[type="text"], select, textarea` has a higher specificity than your `.lastfld` class, so the `margin-right: 2%` ends up overriding your `margin-right: 0;`.

To fix it you could give it a higher specificity by merging the selectors:

```
input[type="text"].lastfld {margin-right: 0;}
```

Another route would be to add ´!important‘ to your css attribute; this will automatically give it the highest specificity, but I highly suggest you don't go down that route. In my experience, using !importants will bite you in the back most of the times.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: navy;
}

.frm {
  /* border: 1px solid green; */
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  background-color: #f2f2f2; /* light gray */
}

.row {
  /*border: 1px dashed red;*/
  width: 100%;
  margin: 18px 0;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row::after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}

.col-lbl {
  display: inline-block;
  /*float: left;*/

  border: 1px dotted green;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
}

.col-flds {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;

  border: 1px dotted blue;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type="text"],
select,
textarea {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;

  border: 1px solid #ccc; /* light grey */
  margin-right: 2%; /* default right margin */
  padding: 12px 20px;
}

textarea {
  height: 200px;
  resize: none;
}

input[type="text"].lastfld {margin-right: 0;}

input[type="text"]:focus,
select:focus,
textarea:focus {
  border: 2px solid #555;
}

#fname,
#lname {
  width: 100%;
}

#city {
  width: 58%;
}

#ZIP {
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<h1>PERSONAL DETAILS - 3</h1>

<div class="frm">
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lbl">
        <label for="fname">First Name</label>
      </div>

      <div class="col-flds">
        <input type="text" class="lastfld" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your first name">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lbl">
        <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
      </div>

      <div class="col-flds">
        <input type="text" class="lastfld" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lbl">
        <label>City / ZIP</label>
      </div>

      <div class="col-flds">
        <input type="text" id="city" name="city" placeholder="City">

        <input type="text" class="lastfld" id="ZIP" name="ZIP" placeholder="ZIP">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Good find! I didn't spot that

Comment: Specificity. A wonderful explanation. And absolutely right too. I should have thought of this. Next time, I'll be more careful. Thanks.

Comment: This was a weird case to me. If you had asked me which one of the selectors has higher specificity, I would have said .lastfld. As far as I know class selectors are more specific then element selectors, I suspect that adding [type="text"] adds quite a bit to it's specificity.

Comment: @SSteven I tested this here: https://jsfiddle.net/f6vp0s15/1/ if you uncomment the commented css part you'll see both input become blue. This means that .test is more specific than input, but input[type="text"] is more specific than .test. Good to know, I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1):

[Jonas Grumann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1254917/jonas-grumann) has it right in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56074763/476951). It's a matter of [specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/#article-header-id-0)

`input[type="text"]` has a specificity of `0011`, while
`.lastfld` has a specifity of `0010`
`0011` overrules `0010`, so the `input[type="text"]` wins over `.lastfld`

### What you can do about it?

1. Make the small specificity higher: Change `.lastfld` to `input[type="text"]:last-child` (`0010` > `0021`)
2. Make the big specificity smaller: Change `input[type="text"]` to `[type="text"]` (`0011` > `0010`)
3. Use style attribute: `style="margin-right: 0"` which has a specificity of `1000`
4. Overrule with `!important` (This could be seen as adding a specificity of 10000, but that's not official lingo)

**I'd go for 1) or 2)**
3) is acceptable, but not recommended, 4) is not recommended at all. Us it only as the very last straw, for example, if you need to style HTML code which you cannot change and which uses style attributes.

## 1)

```
input[type="text"],
select,
textarea {
  /* ... */
  margin-right: 2%;
  /* ... */
}

/* This way you don't need class lastfld anymore */
input[type="text"]:last-child,
select:last-child,
textarea:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

or

## 2)

```
[type="text"],
select,
textarea {
  /* ... */
  margin-right: 2%;
  /* ... */
}
.lastfld {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

You can calculate and compare your specificity here: [Specificity Calculator](http://specificity.keegan.st/)

Answer (score 0):

use float for this you will get your desired result I have done it please check it.

```css
#city {
  width: 58%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  float: left;
}

.lastfld {
  margin-right: 0;
}

#city {
  width: 58%;
}

#ZIP {
  width: 38%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lbl">
    <label>City / ZIP</label>
  </div>

  <div class="col-flds">
    <input type="text" 
           id="city" name="city" 
           placeholder="City">

    <input type="text" 
           class="lastfld" 
           id="ZIP" name="ZIP" 
           placeholder="ZIP">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code get the margin-right priority here

```
input[type="text"], select, textarea {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-right: 2%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
}
```

Two ways

Specify with selector and it is the perfect way.

```
input[type="text"].lastfld {
    margin-right: 0px
}
```

Or use important.
But using !important is not recommended.

```
.lastfld {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Important is a bad suggestion. Specificity exists for a reason. Make your selector more specific, or else some time you’ll inevitably want to override that !important, but the only way to do that is with another !important at higher specificity. Next thing you know, everything is important.

Comment: You’re absolutely right. I tried to explain both way. But !important should be the last option.